# PHP7 hides parse errors during autoload

Tags: error-handling, spl-autoload-register, php-7

I have a class A extending class B. Class A is autoloaded during reflection, which in turn autoloads class B.
When there is a parse in class B, I only get an exception saying class A does not exist, the parse error in class B is hidden.

A usable solution would be to somehow catch the parse error when running require_once, but the parse error should ideally be handled the normal way rather than be hidden.

Comment: If you think it is a bug, please create a *self-contained* reproduce script and create a report on bugs.php.net.

Comment: given the nature of this issue, it would need to be two files at minimum, is that still considered a self-contained reproduce script?

Comment: Yes, that's fine :) Though one can easily reduce it to one file using eval() to trigger the parse error.

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce this issue, sadly. If it crops up again, I will try to do it then.